# HtmlCleaner Using ContentNodes and modifying the text content

Tags: java, coldfusion, htmlcleaner

I am using HtmlCleaner with ColdFusion. In the code below I am traversing the node tree and looking for content nodes. What I want to do is be able to modify the text content of the node.

```
node.traverse(new TagNodeVisitor() {
    public boolean visit(TagNode tagNode, HtmlNode htmlNode) {
         if (htmlNode instanceof ContentNode) {
            ContentNode content = ((ContentNode) htmlNode); 
            String textContent = content.getContent();
        }
        // tells visitor to continue traversing the DOM tree
        return true;
    }
});
```

The example I am using is:

```
    // traverse whole DOM and update images to absolute URLs
node.traverse(new TagNodeVisitor() {
    public boolean visit(TagNode tagNode, HtmlNode htmlNode) {
        if (htmlNode instanceof TagNode) {
            TagNode tag = (TagNode) htmlNode;
            String tagName = tag.getName();
            if ("img".equals(tagName)) {
                String src = tag.getAttributeByName("src");
                if (src != null) {
                    tag.setAttribute("src", Utils.fullUrl(siteUrl, src));
                }
            }
        } else if (htmlNode instanceof CommentNode) {
            CommentNode comment = ((CommentNode) htmlNode); 
            comment.getContent().append(" -- By HtmlCleaner");
        }
        // tells visitor to continue traversing the DOM tree
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i wanted to do was grab the content between the html tags so that i can translate them to another language , without messing with html tags,images, ect...

```
    node.traverse(new TagNodeVisitor() {
    public boolean visit(TagNode tagNode, HtmlNode htmlNode) {
    if (htmlNode instanceof ContentNode) {
            ContentNode content = ((ContentNode) htmlNode); 
            URLConnection urlConn;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String USER_AGENT =  "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)";
            String text = content.getContent();
            String strUrl = "http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=t&sl=#arguments.FromLanguage#&tl=#arguments.ToLanguage#&hl=#arguments.ToLanguage#&sc=2&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&oc=1&otf=1&ssel=0&tsel=0&q=" + URLEncoder.encode(text);
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);
            urlConn = url.openConnection();
            urlConn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                            "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream(),
                            "utf-8");

            JsonArray gRet = new Gson().fromJson(reader, JsonArray.class);
            StringBuffer newContent = new StringBuffer(1000);
            gRet.get(0)?.each() { el -> newContent.append(el.getAsJsonArray()?.get(0)?.getAsString()); };

            tagNode.insertChildAfter(htmlNode, new ContentNode(newContent.toString()));
            tagNode.removeChild(htmlNode);

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with HtmlCleaner, does it only perform "cleaning"?  I can't find any method to set text values.
http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html

jsoup is a full HTML parser (written in Java) that works with DOM elements just like using jQuery.  I use the text() setter method to update text nodes.
http://jsoup.org/cookbook/modifying-data/set-text

```
// intitial: <div></div>
div = doc.select("div").first();
div.text("five > four");
div.prepend("First ");
div.append(" Last");
// now: <div>First five &gt; four Last</div>
```

More info on jsoup (and ColdFusion):

- http://jsoup.org/
- http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2358-parsing-traversing-and-mutating-html-with-coldfusion-and-jsoup.htm
- http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/4/6/jsoup-adds-jQuerylike-parsing-in-Java

Comment: I am aware of jsoup, but the Htmlcleaner site does give an example where they append text to a comment node. via comment.getContent().append(" -- By HtmlCleaner"); but when I try it it errors.

Comment: @user3653457: That's information that really should be in your question post.

Comment: James is there an example that traverses all text nodes so i can modify them. It needs to be dynamic, I am not looking for a specific tag.

Comment: It'd be beneficial to know what you are trying to accomplish in the end.  If you really want to traverse all nodes you can use .select("*").  This will give you an array that you can loop over and perform logic on text().  There's also a textnode method http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/TextNode.html